# Apply Gravity to Car Physics

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was moving a car in the city area within my game.
Moving the car by applying continuous velocity:

```
  appliedSpeed += Time.deltaTime * 10f;
  appliedSpeed = Mathf.Min(appliedSpeed, speed);
  myRigidbody.velocity = transform.forward * appliedSpeed;
```

Now as an issue, gravity is not get affected. Though Physics gravity is set to -9.8 within settings.
My player car rigidbody inspector values, I have shown in the below image.

[image]

At present, the player car can able to run above the water area too. I don't want that, naturally, it should require to fall into the water.
I want this implementation, what should I require to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `rigidbody.AddForce()` instead of changing `.velocity` directly.

You are effectivelly overriding the effects of gravity when you set `.velocity`, and that's why it's not having an effect.

---

Extra tip:

If you use a `ForceMode` representing a continuous force (`Force` to take mass into account and `Acceleration` to ignore mass) and `.AddForce()` inside `FixedUpdate`, you don't need to scale the force by the delta-time. The engine will do this for you.

Comment: But I want to move my car at a constant speed so that I have applied velocity directly. If I apply force then it will get a continuous increase.

Comment: One more problem with force, car controlling big touch when you are moving with force, its sliding in game...

Comment: Your first problem is easily solved by clamping the magnitude of speed rather than setting it, or by balancing the force and drag such that the max speed matches your desired speed. --- The second problem is just a matter of setup. Increase your drag to make stops faster. Increase force magnitude to make acceleration faster. Have a script do rotations directly for an arcady feel, or have a full wheel rig for realistic turning. --- In the worst case scenario and an alternative I _**don't**_ reccomend: Just add gravity after changes to `.velocity`, since that was the problem in the first place.